# How to add links to multiple files easily?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

I wanted to add links to my OneNote document that link to certain files on my computer.
I can do this by going to "Insert", then "Link" and then selecting the file. But the problem is that I have to add hundreds of links each referring to a different file. It's very tedious to do it one by one for each file. It doesn't let me select more than one file when I try to add a link.

Dragging and dropping more than one file works, but the text it displays is of the location and not of the name of the file. So I was wondering if there was any way I could do this easily? Maybe with a plugin?